# Setting the initial state of redux in reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Hey guys i am stuck in a situation in which i have to set the inital state of reducer to some value let me show you the code

First of all i have an action creater like this

```
export const fetchuser = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/currentuser");
    dispatch({
      type: "fetchuser",
      payload: res.data
    });
  };
};
```

which just fetches the data from api and dispatches an action to reducer

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "fetchuser":
      return action.payload||false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

now in second action creater i have to  make a post request and increase the "credits" value in user database

```
export const handletoken = token => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.post("/api/stripe", token);
    dispatch({ type: "credits", payload: res.data });
  };
};
```

so i get the updated value here then i pass this on to the reducer

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "credits":
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and then combine them in reducer/index.js

```
export default combineReducers({
auth: authreducer,
credits:creditsreducer
});
```

console log of auth reducer in app.js in mapstatetoprops function gives

```
 auth:
credits: 40
googleid: "109463598810933991924"
__v: 0
_id: "5d7fff2c4cb0604139055ce4"
```

so in credits reducer as u can see i have defined initial value of state as an empty object but i want to set it as the value of credits key of auth reducer, I could easily set it to array or an object hardcoding it but here i need to set its value as a value which is already in my another reducer so how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to wait for `"fetchuser"` to succeed to set credits in your `creditsreducer` you can handle the `"fetchuser"` action in your `creditsreducer` as well:

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "fetchuser":
      return action.payload ? action.payload.credits : state;
    case "credits":
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always keep previous reducer state value. Otherwise no use of redux state value. like this

```
1.export default function(state = {}, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case "fetchuser":
        let data = action.payload||false;
        return {
          ...state,
          fetchuser: data       //any where you can access fetchuser data as well as previous state will not change.
        }
      default:
        return state;
   }
 }
```

Change all the reducers like above.

Comment: ok understood but now how in another reducer i would set the initial state to this state? like here how would i access fetchuser property ?